# Wrap lstinline correctly and globally

Tags: listings, sloppy

This question has apparently come up again and again, but it's been a while with no solution I can find, so I thought I'd ask again.

Consider this:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,pagesize=auto,hidelinks,cleardoublepage=empty]{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{inline code}{RGB}{194,61,53}
\newcommand*{\code}{\lstinline[basicstyle=\fontsize{9}{11}\ttfamily\color{inline code},keywordstyle=\color{inline code},stringstyle=\color{inline code}]}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{black!30!white}

\blindtext

Here is a sample paragraph that is just the right length. And here is some \code{ExampleCodeThatIsLong} within that paragraph.

\begin{sloppypar}
Here is a sample paragraph that is just the right length. And here is some \code{ExampleCodeThatIsLong} within that paragraph.
\end{sloppypar}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

The rendering is thusly:

[image]

Obviously my problem is the `ExampleCodeThatIsLong` dangling in the second paragraph. The third paragraph "solves" the issue by using `sloppypar`, but it requires me to wrap the paragraph. Given that my book has a *lot* of `\inlinecode` usage, I will effectively need to wrap *every* paragraph in a `sloppypar`! And I haven't even checked to see what happens with inline code inside a footnote, for example...

I'm aware I can also add `,draft` to my `documentclass` options to get a visualization of the problem:

[image]

But that won't save me the hassle of adding `sloppypar` everywhere.

How can I have my inline code *always* behave like it does under `sloppypar`? Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: there are several solutions depending what you want, justify the paragraph allowing more space (sloppy) or give up on justification around the unbreakable word (eg `\\ `)  or allow the word to hyphenate or allow the word to break without hyphenation, also do you really need arbitrary inline code, or just long words?

Comment: for example you could use `\textcolor{red}{\ttfamily Example\-Code\-That\-Is\-Long}` to allow the word to break at camel case boundaries.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My expectation is that it be moved to the next line - I don't want it split up in any way. Basically, that it behaves like it does when `sloppypar` is applied.

Comment: how were we to guess that? You can use `\hspace*{\fill}}` at the start of the definition of `\code` but if you want the entire paragraph to reflow you need that at the start, perhaps just put `\sloppy` in the preamble of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still not quite clear what output you want. If you want the large unbreakable text to go over the line but the entire paragraph still to justify you need to change the paragraph settings so either `sloppypar` for a small region or perhaps just put

```
\sloppy
```

in the document preamble to make this the default.

Alternatively if you just want to make a local change to the white space around the code you could use

```
\newcommand*{\code}{\hspace*{0pt plus .2\linewidth}\linebreak[0]\hspace*{0pt plus -.2\linewidth}%
  \lstinline[basicstyle=\fontsize{9}{11}\ttfamily\color{inline code},keywordstyle=\color{inline code},stringstyle=\color{inline code}]}
```

That would allow the line to be short by 20% of the line width. You could reduce the `.2\linewidth` to allow less short lines (the shorter you make this the more you encourage any other inter-word spaces on the line to stretch to compensate) If you want to ensure that it is never overfull you could allow it to be `1\linewidth`  You could also use infinite stretch such as `1fill` but that would stop any of the inter-word spaces stretching and move all "extra" space to the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks, `sloppy` as the default is what I was after. Sorry I didn't make that clearer. Weird that I didn't find that as an answer in all the other questions I found about this issue.